# Define theme information other than through style.css

Tags: themes

I'd like to define a theme's information through other means (i.e., xml, plain php, yml, json, etc) - Is that possible? If so, how?

By "theme information" I meant the following:

```
/*   
Theme Name: Minimum Theme
Description: Test
Author: Test
Version: 1.0
*/
```

Comment: Yes you can do that with any file. You can define global variables.

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: You can include a PHP file in `wp-config.php` or in functions with `init` hook and define your information. For example, `define( 'DEVELOPER_NAME', 'Robert Hue' );`. Now you can use this anywhere in WordPress you want.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure we're on the same page, so I updated my question a bit.

Comment: I disagree with @Roberthue. I'm now writting an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The presence of `style.css` with a name is a hard requirement for a valid theme.

From quick look through the code it's unlikely you can easily work around it. However it seems you can manipulate rest of the data. There is dynamic `extra_{$context}_headers` hook in `get_file_data()`, so filtering `extra_theme_headers` will probably let you splice data in from different source.

Comment: It seems that I understood the question in the opposite way. From theme headers to other sources. But reading again the question I was wrong. I've deleted my answer, so.

Comment: Thanks for the information, very helpful. Sorry, couldn't upvote your answer - don't have enough reps yet.